# Why do i get repository error in terminal when i want to update ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

When i use **sudo apt update** command in terminal to see if there are a new updates for packages i get repository error like below :

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can i solve that?

Comment: Probably this repo is abandoned. There is no supported `focal` distribution if you just click http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: @AlexeyR. i don't need that repository at all neither pepper-flash . do you know any command to stop that error? i just want to update my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open terminal.
2. Then: `cd /etc/apt`
3. Then: `grep -Ril "pepper-flash" .`
4. Then clear or comment the entries related to "pepper-flash" repo in the files you have received on previous step.
5. Then do `sudo apt update`

Say you have detected that the repos are defined in

```
sources.list.d/skunk-ubuntu-pepper-flash-focal.list.save
sources.list.d/skunk-ubuntu-pepper-flash-focal.list
```

Then run the command `sudo rm sources.list.d/skunk-ubuntu-pepper-flash-focal.list*`

Comment: ````sources.list.d/skunk-ubuntu-pepper-flash-focal.list.save```` first one
````sources.list.d/skunk-ubuntu-pepper-flash-focal.list```` second one . How can i remove these 2 entries? which command should i use? im not that familiar with linux commands.@AlexeyR.

Comment: See my update in the answer